# Authorization in webapp2?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

In the webapp2 [documentation](http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/webapp2_extras/auth.html) for webapp2_extras.auth, it defines the class as:

> "Utilities for authentication and authorization."

However, I don't see anything necessarily related to authorization (for example access to administrator-only pages).

I've created my own work-around to this by creating my own authorization methods to check the datastore for user-privileges, but is there something I'm missing here for authorization via webapp2, or is this just an incomplete class?

Comment: https://blog.abahgat.com/2013/01/07/user-authentication-with-webapp2-on-google-app-engine/

Comment: Yes, but what about authorization of users, for example super-users or admin-users who have access to only admin-only authorized pages?